# osb project deployment failing due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: osb

I am trying to publish a osb project on the osb server. However I am getting below error.

```
com.bea.alsb.core.repositories.RepositoryException
    at com.bea.alsb.core.internal.repositories.jar.AbstractConfigRepository.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.alsb.core.internal.repositories.jar.ServerConfigRepository.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.alsb.core.internal.repositories.RepositoryService.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.alsb.server.publish.ALSBPublishOperation.publishNewContainer(Unknown Source)
    at com.bea.alsb.server.publish.ALSBPublishOperation.execute(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.performTasks(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1311)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:855)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:686)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3027)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.bea.alsb.server.core.ClientMBeanService$MBeanInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at $Proxy54.uploadJarFile(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Please note that I have provided below parameter in server startup, but still facing the same issue.
XX:MaxPermSize=512m

Comment: Perm gen space is not the same as heap space.

Answer (score 0):

How are you starting your managed server? Using node manager/startManagedWeblogic? 
If node manager is used to start to MS, then try hanging permsize to 768 MB. If you use startManagedWeblogic to start your MS, then please note that the parameter you added at server startup is not taken into consideration while MS startup.